# Push Notification to FCM from SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an SQL table that keeps record of what notification is to be send and delete the record once it successfully send to FCM.

What I am doing now:- I have a backend application developed in Visual Basic that keeps checking for any new records in the table every 5 seconds, and it sends notification to the user based on the record fund. (Records in the notification table are inserted from multiple table triggers).

Is this an efficient way ? or is there any other open source application or plug in that I can use to achieve the same without overloading SQL Server with queries every 5 seconds ?

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: *Is this an efficient way ?* - somewhere between "no" and "depends how 'new records' is determined"

Comment: new notifications are inserted using triggers into notification_que_table when new records inserted or updated in orders table

Comment: And you must process them every 5 seconds ?

Comment: Couldn't you have the triggers send the notifications?

Comment: I don't have any idea if I can send data to FCM from SQL Server , currently I'm retrieving data from table with a backend app developed in Visual Basic and using it to FCM.